# Falcon 9's description of component mass

Tags: falcon-9

What is the component mass of SpaceX's Falcon 9 or any 
descriptions that could tell the component mass of SpaceX's Falcon 9.

Comment: there are no official figures. Decent guesses can be found at http://www.spacelaunchreport.com/falcon9.html

Comment: you were pertaining to the vehicle components from the link given and all of it are the mass descriptions? the shaded part means rough or exact measurement?

Comment: The shaded parts of the specification table are rockets that were planned but have never flown.

Comment: Are you asking for a breakdown of the weight of the parts of the falcon9? for example a merlin engine weights Xkg, and the landing legs weight Ykg?

Comment: just Description on component mass of the Launch Vehicle LV which is Falcon 9